# how to track googlemaps events?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps

I am trying to log events in Googlemaps. So for example when a user zooms into a map I would like to log this through a server asp.net server call? what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I've actually implemented something like this recently.

If the map JavaScript is stored in object `map`.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(
    map, 
    "center_changed", 
    updateMapState
);

google.maps.event.addListener(
    map, 
    "bounds_changed", 
    updateMapState
);
```

Then, `updateMapState` is a function like what follows.

```
function updateMapState() {
    var
        center = map.getCenter(),
        zoom = map.getZoom();

    $.post(
        "/site/ajax/action", {
            latitude:center.lat(),
            longitude:center.lng(),
            zoom:zoom
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a WCF/.ASMX/ASP.NET WebMethod web service and call it via AJAX from the client-side for any event or action you wish.